# Can `apt` be used to install only the `man` page for a package

Tags: apt, aptitude

As the title asks, is it possible to install only the `man` page for a package - without installing the package itself? If so - what `apt` options are needed to make this happen?

I've reviewed `man apt`, `man apt-get`, `man apt-preferences` & done a brief [online search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=apt+install+only+man+page+for+a+package&t=ffnt&ia=web). I didn't find anything that addressed this specific question.

[This search result came closest](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-add-install-man-pages-on-ubuntu-linux/). Running `apt-cache search manpages` revealed a few *selected* manuals, but not, for example, how to get the manpage for `watchdog`.

Comment: I have never heard of such an option.  I think few man pages (if any) are large enough to warrant a package separate to the application.

Comment: Depending on the info you are trying to get you could use something like TLDR pages https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr. Also, your question does describe the use case but the web will also offer up the webpage (though getting the correct version can be difficult.

Comment: You could also do it manually or script it (download, ensure the correct format and move to correct directory) most man page authoring tutorials will cover this..

Comment: @SteveRobillard: I found an answer that seems to work: `debman`. It's not ideal, but it seems to have gotten the job done in this case.

Comment: @joan: I hadn't either until just now. I posted this as a question w/ no answer, then almost immediately stumbled on something that seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41502/286615) turned up in a slightly different search. The link provided in the answer is apparently an [obsolete page](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/454) now. However, the following yielded a result that may answer the question:

```bsh
$ apt-cache search debman
debian-goodies - Small toolbox-style utilities for Debian systems 

$ sudo apt-get install debian-goodies
```

So far, so good... `man debman` exists (as does `debman -h`), but not very clear IMHO. Nevertheless, this seems to have gotten the job done:

```bsh
$ debman -p watchdog watchdog
Get:1 http://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf watchdog armhf 5.15-2 [82.5 kB]
Fetched 82.5 kB in 1s (102 kB/s)
```

Followed by `man watchdog` :

> WATCHDOG(8)                                               System Manager's Manual                                               WATCHDOG(8)
>
> NAME
> watchdog - a software watchdog daemon
>
> SYNOPSIS
> watchdog [-F|--foreground] [-f|--force] [-c filename|--config-file filename] [-v|--verbose] [-s|--sync] [-b|--softboot] [-q|--no-ac‐
> tion]